# Outputting single file for partitioner

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, partitioner

Trying to get as many reducer as the no of keys

```
public class CustomPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, Text>
{
    public int getPartition(Text key, Text value,int numReduceTasks)
   {
        System.out.println("In CustomP");
       return (key.toString().hashCode()) % numReduceTasks;
   }
}
```

Driver class

```
job6.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job6.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job6.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
job6.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job6.setMapperClass(LastMapper.class);
job6.setReducerClass(LastReducer.class);
job6.setPartitionerClass(CustomPartitioner.class);
job6.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job6.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

But I am getting ootput in a single file.

Am I doing anything wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not control number of reducer without specifying it :-). But still there is no surety of getting all the keys on different reducer because you are not sure how many distinct keys you would get in the input data and your hash partition function may return same number for two distinct keys. If you want to achieve your solution then you'll have to know number of distinct keys in advance and then modify your partition function accordingly.

Comment: partitioners job is to write output to different reducers right?So how can I get different files for different keys.And we may not be knowing how many keys can generate

Comment: Yes. Could you tell me how many distinct keys you are having in the data? Simpler way to find it out by using a small pig script. Then with the help of those distinct values (should not be very big <= 100), use multi output format feature. Another way is to write a custom partition which sends every new key to different reducer (which you would have already specified as number of distinct keys) which you can mange by those distinct keys.

Comment: Although I've suggested some probable solutions but still I won't recommend to have separate part file for each key because in production data there would be chance of having plenty number of distinct keys and this solution will just kill Namenode.

Comment: Thanks for the information Ashish.I will look into some alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the number of reduce tasks that's equal to number of keys and also you need to return the partitions based on your key's in partitioner class. for example if your input having 4 keys(here it is wood,Masonry,Reinforced Concrete etc) then your getPartition method look like this..

```
 public int getPartition(Text key, PairWritable value, int numReduceTasks) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s = value.getone();

        if (numReduceTasks ==0){
            return 0;
        }

        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("wood")){

            return 0;
        }

        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Masonry")){
            return 1%numReduceTasks;
        }

        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Reinforced Concrete")){
            return 2%numReduceTasks;
        }
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Reinforced Masonry")){
            return 3%numReduceTasks;
        }

        else
            return 4%numReduceTasks;

    }   

}
```

corresponding output will be collected in respective reducers..**Try Running in CLI instead eclipse**

Answer (score 0):

You haven't configured the number of reducers to run.  
You can configure it using below API

> job.setNumReduceTasks(10); //change the number according to your
>   cluster

Also, you can set while executing from commandline

> -D mapred.reduce.tasks=10

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i need to output different output files for different keys(as amny keys I need seperate file)

Answer (score 0):

Veni, You need to Chain the Tasks as below

```
Mapper1 --> Reducer --> Mapper2 (Post Processing Mapper which creates
file for Each key)
```

Mapper 2 is InputFormat should be NlineInputFormat, so the output of the reducer that is for each key there will be corresponding mapper and Mapper output will be a separate file foe each key.

Mapper 1 and Reducer is your existing MR job.

Hope this helps.

Cheers 
Nag